# Laravel, optimize query?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I want to get all users from some groups. However, some things confuse me. I wrote something that works but I wish to simplify that if possible.

```
$groups = Group::with('users')->whereIn('id',array(78,160))->get();

$users = new Collection;
foreach ($groups as $group) {
    foreach ($group->users as $user) {
        $users->add($user);
    }
}

$u = $users->unique();

foreach ($u as $user) {
    echo $user->name;
}
```

I tried distinct within "with('users')" but didn't work as expected. I also tried to fetch from User model side but didn't work too:

```
$users = User::with(array('groups' => function($q){
      $q->whereIn('id',array(78,160));
}))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely can't do it using `with` as it first loads all groups then uses another query to get all users for this groups.

The answers are

```
$users = User::whereHas('groups', function($q){
      $q->whereIn('id',array(78,160));
})->get();
```

or

```
$users = User::join('users_groups', 'users.id', '=', 'users_groups.user_id')->whereIn('users_groups.group_id', [78, 160])->get(['users.*']);
```

Comment: 1st and 3rd are wrong, `whereHas` is the way to go. You can use `join` as well, but then you **need** `select` (or `get( columns )`), most likely `select('users.*')`, otherwise the result will be wrong and you may even not notice it for long time of scratching your head...

Comment: For some reason, even 2. doesn't work for me at all. I can't get an error output due to some stupid ajax.

Comment: I edited my answer so try the one with ```whereHas```.